# Two Dimensional Array not Working correctly

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
String Hello = "abc";
        rowValue.add(Hello);
        completeData.add(rowValue);
        System.out.println(" One " +completeData);
        rowValue.clear();
        String value= "def";
        rowValue.add(value);
        completeData.add(rowValue);
        System.out.println(" Two " +completeData);
```

Output:
 One [[abc]]
 Two [[def], [def]]...

How to get output as:
 One [[abc]]
 TWo [[abc], [def]]

I am not sure, What is happening after Clear() function call.

Comment: static ArrayList<String> rowValue = new ArrayList<String>();
 static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> completeData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `clear`. You are adding one reference. Change

```
rowValue.clear();
```

to something like

```
rowValue = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.It worked perfectly. A small mistake took a huge chunk of my time.